# how to display visual force tab visible by Default

Tags: permission-sets, visualforce-tab

I was asked to show a visual force tab in the home page by default to a set of users.

So I have created a permission set in which I have selected the visual force tab from the object settings and checked the Available and visible checkbox and saved.And then I have assigned the permission sets to the set of users.

But the visual force tab is not visible by default for the users. When I click the customize my tabs button it is visible in the available tabs.

But all I want is to show the tab by default once the user logged in. Please provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: Im assuming you are in classic.   you need to add the tab to an app.  then It will be visible by default for new users.  For existing users you have to check the override existing tabs checkbox when editing the app but BEWARE as this will undo all customization already done by the user so should be used very judiciously.

Comment: Great will add an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming you are in classic.   You need to add the tab to an app.  Then It will be visible by default for new users.

To make the tab visible for existing users you have to check the override existing tabs checkbox when editing the app but BEWARE as this will undo all tab customization already done by the user so should be used very judiciously.